# Can't run ajax with php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to php and ajax. I want to run simple code of ajax with php but the code is not working as intended. I want load some text in the page when onchange happen

source code
ajax.php

```
<select id='mySelect' onChange="MyFunction()">
    <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
    <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
    <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
</select>




<script>

function MyFunction()
{
    var params="myName=2";
    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlHttp.open("GET","edittest.php",true);
    if(xmlHttp)
    {

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
        {

            alert(document.getElementById('mySelect').value);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.send(params);
    }

</script>
```

edittest.php
source code

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET))
{
    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
    {
        echo($_GET['myName']);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you verified that the final URL request is for `edittest.php?myName=2`?

Comment: Try using jquery ajax best describe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: it is not showing as edittest.php?myName=2 it shows ajax.php

Comment: He meant the Ajax request. If you use Chrome, press F12, go to the network tab, change an option on your select box, and see what happens. Does the request get sent at all? Does it return a 2** status code, is the url  `edittest.php?myName=2`?

Comment: edit1: xmlHttp.open("GET","edittest.php?myName=2",true);  edit2: xmlHttp.send(null);

Comment: Check My edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a much simpler experience, I suggest you use jQuery AJAX.
Here is the code. Check the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

```
function MyFunction()
{
    var myName=2;
$.ajax({
    url: "/edittest.php",
    data: {
        myName: myName
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Did u include jqeury?

Comment: use Firebug in Firefox, Press F12 to view the console, then click onChange, and see the output in Console. It would be helpful if you could post the response from ur console.

Comment: do I have to install any plugins for ajax!!! I installed apache 2.4 and php I used dreamweaver and all in one zend studio and php designer 8 I tried everything but the same result.

Comment: No u dont need any extra plugin for Ajax with simple javascript ... but if u r using jquery then u will need to include the jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you declare `var params="myName=2";`, but you never use it. Your script works, but since it is just requesting the `edittest.php`, it wont show you anything, since your PHP script only prints out the `myName` variable.

You should add the parameters at the end of your request like this:

```
<select id='mySelect' onChange="MyFunction()">
    <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
    <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
    <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
</select>

<script>
    function MyFunction() {
        var params = "myName=2";
        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlHttp.open("GET", "edittest.php?" + params, true);
        if (xmlHttp) {
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(document.getElementById('mySelect').value);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send(params);
    }
</script>
```

(Notice the `xmlHttp.open("GET", "edittest.php?" + params, true);` part.)

Comment: thanks for your effort but it seems the same result. also I tried to use post with xmlHttp.send(params); and the result the same

Comment: @IS_ELKADY If you use Google Chrome, press the F12 key, go to the network tab, and change your `mySelect` box, to see what happens. That can narrow down your problem. (Check if the request is sent, and if so what status you get back)